# dijkstra's algorithm - how to return edge weights in path

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

I am working on a project to implement Dijkstra's shortest route algorithm in java. I have used this version in my program : [LINK](http://en.literateprograms.org/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm_%28Java%29)

My program takes a source and gives me output like this:

```
Distance to PE Hall: 0.0 Path: [PE Hall]

Distance to Reception: 1.0 Path: [PE Hall, Reception]

Distance to Stairs: 3.0 Path: [PE Hall, Stairs]

Distance to Refectory: 7.0 Path: [PE Hall, Stairs, Refectory]
```

What I really want is the output to give me the distances between each node in the path, for example:

```
Distance to Refectory: 7.0 Path: [PE Hall 0.0, Stairs 3.0, Refectory 4.0]
```

-

---

### UPDATE

I realised the program stores paths by adding a "previous vertex" variable in each vertex. 
My output is exactly how I want it, but, the distances my method returns by iterating back over the path are not correct.

```
Target = E250 Distance = 0.0 {E250=0.0}
Target = D Distance = 10.0 {E250=0.0, D=10.0}
Target = C250Trans Distance = 35.0 {E250=0.0, C250Trans=10.0, D=10.0}
```

here is the method I use to create an arraylist with the path and distances between each point

```
public static ArrayList<String> getShortestPaths(Vertex target)
  {
      ArrayList<String> path = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
        {   
             path.add(vertex.name + "=" + vertex.getDistFromPrev());
        }
      Collections.reverse(path);
      return path;
  }
```

And here is the method I use to get the distances between each point in the path, contained in the vertex class:

```
 public double getDistFromPrev()
{
    double weight = 0.;
    for(Edge e : adjacencies){
        if(e.target == this.previous){
            weight = e.weight;
        }
    }
    return weight;
}
```

here is the distance matrix for reference:

> E250 - D = 10
>
> D - C250 = 25

if someone could please clarify why iterating over the path using each vertex's `previous` variable is returning incorrect edge distances that would help me greatly.

Comment: When you update distance to node also remember "incoming vertex". As result you can take distance from latest vertex to start vertex.

Comment: some one help me please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the path:

```
PE Hall, Stairs, Refectory
```

You also know the distances to every location in the path:

```
PE Hall: 0.0 
Reception: 1.0 
Stairs: 3.0 
Refectory: 7.0
```

Dijkstra's **is** giving you the information you want, you just need to "format" it appropriately (e.g. write a small helper function that combines the data and call your helper after Dijkstra's is done).

Answer (score 0):

Let `s` be the starting vertex of your path, `d(v)` be the distance of vertex `v` to vertex `s` and let `e = w->v` be an edge of the path. Then the length of `e` is `d(v) - d(w)`. In your example, the length of the edge `Stairs -> Refectory` is `7.0 - 3.0 = 4.0`